# How to use bones to control the shape key checkbox

Tags: drivers, shape-keys

I'm a dump....

When I making my rig, I somehow knew how to control the shape key's checkbox by the local location of the bone. here is how it work looks like:
[image]

And recently I find a bug of my rig. some how the second and the third shapekey will be unchecked when I move the Armature in the world space... but I forget how a acheived "control the shope key's sheckbox by the local location" in the first place....

Any help?

Here is the blender file if needed:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qpzyDn7F8ACyQqitAqmRts-wqdgbmqHm/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you used the technique of creating an action for the shapekey buttons and then assigned the action to a bone via an action constraint.  If you did, you probably used something like these steps:

- Use the Dope Sheet, action editor to create an action.

  - Give it a name.
  - Give it a fake user for safety.
  - Create (or identify a bone that will be used as the controller
  - For each bone that has key frames in the action:

    - Add an action constraint to the bone
    - Set the target to the control bone
    - Set the target properties.  Moving on X is a good choice

      - Channel: X Location
      - Target Local Space
      - Range Min 0 / Max 1
    - Set the Action to the name of the action in step 2

Although, of course, your constraint would "programmed" differently than my example.